# EKS - internal LB or ndoeport

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-elb, kubernetes-service, internal-load-balancer

I have an EKS cluster running in one VPC and some ec2 instances on a legacy VPC, the 2 VPCs has peering between them.

I have a app on the EKS cluster needs to be reachable from inside the cluster and also to the ec2 instances on the legacy VPC.

Do I need to create 2 services for the app - one kind: clusterIP for in cluster communication and one kine: LoadBalancer for external VPC communication:

```
annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
```

OR - I can create only one service kind: nodeport/clusterIP/LB internal for both in-cluster and external VPC communication?

What is the preferred way.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Do I need to create 2 services for the app...create only one service kind: nodeport/clusterIP/LB internal for both in-cluster and external VPC communication?`

You need only one service in this case. Either a typed NodePort where you get a cluster IP (for connection within the k8s cluster network); plus a port accessible at EC2 worker node. Typed LoadBalancer gets you a cluster IP too; plus the LB endpoint. As worker nodes come and go, LB give you more flexibility as you will only dealing with a known endpoint.